# PIL Image.resize() not resizing the picture

Tags: python, resize, python-imaging-library

I have some strange problem with PIL not resizing the image.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('foo.jpg')

width, height = img.size
ratio = floor(height / width)
newheight = ratio * 150

img.resize((150, newheight), Image.ANTIALIAS)

img.save('mugshotv2.jpg', format='JPEG')
```

This code runs without any errors and produces me image named `mugshotv2.jpg` in correct folder, but it does not resize it. It does something to it, because the size of the picture drops from 120 kb to 20 kb, but the dimensions remain the same.

Perhaps you can also suggest way to crop images into squares with less code. I kinda thought that `Image.thumbnail` does it, but what it did was that it scaled my image to 150 px by its width, leaving height 100px.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`resize()` returns a resized copy of an image. It doesn't modify the original. The correct way to use it is:

```
from PIL import Image
#...

img = img.resize((150, newheight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

[source](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)

I think what you are looking for is the ImageOps.fit function. From PIL [docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imageops.htm):

> ImageOps.fit(image, size, method, bleed, centering) => image
>
> Returns a sized and cropped version of
> the image, cropped to the requested
> aspect ratio and size. The size
> argument is the requested output size
> in pixels, given as a (width, height)
> tuple.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. This was yet again mistake of this stupid, easy kind, that i often do :P. Looking at it again i cant understand how i did not understand it myself - it was in the damn docs after all. 
I think i need to go to bed. 

Thanks again and ill try out that ImageOps.fit some other day :D

Comment: @Zayatzz, so accept @Nadia's answer, already, since it's solved your problem _and_ even provided advice on even better approaches!

Comment: Ah.. that strange check mark.... ohwell. it could use something to draw more attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

**[Update]**
ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.image.resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)

Answer (score 0):

Today you should use something like this:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(r"C:\test.png")
img.show()
img_resized = img.resize((100, 100), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
img_resized.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).