# Pillow, how to modify a stream object?

Tags: python, stream, python-imaging-library

I'm using pillow in order to format image size.
I have no idea why the transformation is not working and where I did wrong:

```
def upload_file(file, bucketName=""):
    from PIL import Image
    from cStringIO import StringIO

    # file is a FileStorage object. Implement stream io
    file_size = size(file)
    print "A size ", file_size

    img = Image.open(file)
    img.thumbnail((5, 5), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(file, "JPEG")
    file.seek(0)

    file_size = size(file)
    print "B size ", file_size
```

But A and B size output the same length, as if the modification never occured. How can I get the file with the modification made with pillow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIL Image.resize() not resizing the picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252218/pil-image-resize-not-resizing-the-picture)

Comment: `img = img.thumbnail((5, 5), Image.ANTIALIAS)`