# How to resize an image with PIL getbbox to the maximum possible size?

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize sprites to a 96x96 boundary while retaining the aspect ratio.

The following code:

```
im.getbbox()
```

Returns a tuple containing the bounds of the sprite (original backgrounds are transparent), and I am stuck on this next part - I want to take that part of the image and resize it as large as it can possibly go within a 96x96 boundary

Here's an example of some sprites from Pokemon:

[image]

Since some are 80x80, some are 64x64, and the largest are 96x96, I would like to effectively select the contents of the sprite with im.getbbox() and then enlarge it to fit on top of a 96px white background.

Could anyone please help? I'm not sure how to maximise it within the bounds

My current code is as follows:

```
x = 0
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        x+=1
        path = dirname + "/" + filename
        print(path)
        
        im = Image.open(path)
        
        fill_color = (255,255,255)
        im = im.convert("RGBA")
        if im.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA'):
            background = Image.new(im.mode[:-1], im.size, fill_color)
            background.paste(im, im.split()[-1])
            im = background

        imResize = ImageOps.fit(im, (96, 96), Image.BOX, 0, (0.5, 0.5))
        imResize.save("dataset/images/" + str(x) + '.png', 'PNG')
```

It takes the image and pastes it on to a white background and sets the size as 96px. This is fine for the native 96px images but the aspect ratio of the smaller images is ruined. By being able to enlarge them to the maximum bounds of a 96px image then it should prevent this from happening

Thanks!

Comment: You've made a single image of 317x120 pixels rather than 3 images of 80x80, 64x64 and 96x96 so it's now harder to help you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry, I just posted that as an example. There are multiple images of different sizes and I'd like to grab what's in them and expand them within the bounds of 96px with their aspect ratios retained

Comment: can we have an input example ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, made my own pics, here:

```
zY28f_64.png,   zY28f_80.png  , zY28f_96.png
```

[image: zY28f_64.png][image: zY28f_80.png] [image: zY28f_96.png]

ended up with code :

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import os



path= 'images'

x = 0
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        x+=1
        path = dirname + "/" + filename
        print(path)
        
        im = Image.open(path)
        
        im.show()
        
        fill_color = (255,255,255)
        im = im.convert("RGBA")
        if im.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA'):
            background = Image.new(im.mode[:-1], im.size, fill_color)
            # background.paste(im, im.split()[-1])
            background.paste(im)
            im = background
        im_inv = ImageOps.invert(im)   ### make white background black
        imResize = ImageOps.fit(im.crop(im_inv.getbbox()), (96, 96), Image.BOX, 0, (0.5, 0.5))  # im.crop crop on box got from image with black background, Image.getbbox works only with black bacground returning biggest box containing non zero(non black ) pixels
        
        imResize.show()
        
        # imResize.save("dataset/images/" + str(x) + '.png', 'PNG')
```

output:

```
zY28f_64.png2.png , zY28f_80.png1.png , zY28f_96.png3.png
```

[image: zY28f_64.png2.png]   [image: zY28f_80.png1.png]   [image: zY28f_96.png3.png]

main changes here:

make white background black

`im_inv = ImageOps.invert(im)`

im.crop crop on box got from image with black background, Image.getbbox works only with black background returning biggest box containing non zero(non black ) pixels

`imResize = ImageOps.fit(im.crop(im_inv.getbbox()), (96, 96), Image.BOX, 0, (0.5, 0.5))`

Since `ImageOps.fit(...)` line return chopped images, not sure how it works, to keep the entire figures I used code from [PIL Image.resize() not resizing the picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252218/pil-image-resize-not-resizing-the-picture) to get:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import os
import math


path= 'images'

x = 0
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        x+=1
        path = dirname + "/" + filename
        print(path)
        
        im = Image.open(path)
        

        
        fill_color = (255,255,255)
        im = im.convert("RGBA")
        if im.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA'):
            background = Image.new(im.mode[:-1], im.size, fill_color)
            # background.paste(im, im.split()[-1])
            background.paste(im)
            im = background
        im_inv = ImageOps.invert(im)
        
        imResize = im.crop(im_inv.getbbox())
        
        width, height = imResize.size
        print(width, height)
        if height > width:
            ratio = math.floor(height / width)
            newheight = ratio * 96
            print(imResize, ratio, newheight)
            imResize = imResize.resize((96, newheight))
        else:
            ratio = math.floor(width /height )
            newwidth = ratio * 96
            print(imResize, ratio, newwidth)
            imResize = imResize.resize((newwidth, 96))
        

        
        imResize.show()
        print(imResize.size)
        
        imResize.save(path + str(x) + '.png', 'PNG')
```

output:

`zY28f_64.png2.png , zY28f_80.png1.png , zY28f_96.png3.png`

[image: 64] [image: 80] [image: 96]

Comment: of course being png you loose definition making them bigger !!!!